# separate class to store input

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Here is following code:

```
class settings {

     static let SharedInstance = settings()
     var city: String {
        return self.city
     }
}
```

right now, i am able to access this class from a separate view like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var cityLabel: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    cityLabel.text = settings.SharedInstance.city
}
```

but i want to be able to change the value of city within my "`settings`" class, from another view.

Something like:

```
@IBOutlet weak var city: UITextField!
@IBAction func saveButtonClicked(_ sender: AnyObject) {
  settings.SharedInstance.cityVar(city.text)  
  closeKeyboard()
}
```

I dont know how to get from here

My logic is to initiate a `setter` inside my `class`, or maybe a `function` that takes a `string` and changes the variable, just like i tried to do above.

**UPDATE**

I can now set and get the city name in this class:

```
class settings {

   static let SharedInstance = settings()

   var city: String?
   func setCity(city: String){

       self.city = city
   }

}
```

The issue now is that when i access the city variable in my class "settings" in another view, it doesn't show the new value :

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        cityLabel.text = settings.SharedInstance.city

     }
```

I believe it doesn't update the view

Comment: class settings {

  private var _x : Int = 0            
  var x : Int {
    set { _x = 2 * newValue }
    get { return _x / 2 }
  }
}    try this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the following line:

```
var city: String {
    return self.city
}
```

then your `city` is going to be a "get only" property. I don't see any reason why you would have to initialize the variable like this. Please clarify if you do.

What I would suggest is changing your variable so that it is an optional. Then you could change your class to something like this:

```
class settings {

    static let SharedInstance = settings()

    var city: String?

}
```

Then you don't have to create initializers for the class. If you also want to create a setter method in the class as well then you can, e.g.:

```
func setCity(city: String){
    self.city = city
}
```

What this means is now the following method would work:

```
class myClass: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        cityLabel.text = settings.SharedInstance.city
        settings.SharedInstance.city = cityLabel.text
    }

}
```

Comment: hmm, well you are right, it doesn't make sense to have it as a "get only" 
- I tried your code, and it does work IF i declare var city = "something" 

it doesnt seem to understand if i set my city from my view like this: 

@IBAction func saveButtonClicked(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        settings.SharedInstance.setCity(city: city.text!)

Comment: What error does it give for that code? I don't see what's wrong with that implementation.

Comment: no error what so ever :-) It just doesn't do anything when i type into my input box and press my button.

Comment: If you edit your question to contain the relevant code for this, then I can try and see what's going wrong.

Comment: i think its because it doesn't update in my other view eg.     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        cityLabel.text = settings.SharedInstance.city
        
    }

Comment: If these are two different view controllers then yeah, you'll probably want to move it from `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidAppear`. But if they are in the same class, then just update the label's text in the IBAction

Comment: No problem, my pleasure :D

Comment: actually, last quick question. Lets say that i close the app, and open it again on my phone, will it then remember what i entered, or will i have to reenter it? 
if i have to reenter it, what do i have to look at in order for it to store it in the memory of the phone?

Comment: Yeah, that's a completely different issue. It will not remember. Perhaps look into core data, or storing information in .plists. The second option is easier, but it's up to you.

Comment: Thank you again :-)